# How can I change background color for JS code?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to use a different background color for code fragments written in JS. I've managed to change it for PHP code, but I can't see no such option for other languages, like JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: There is no such option. Option exists for PHP because you have to use opening tag (e.g. `<?php`) to specify PHP code block even in `.php` file. But there is no such requirement for JavaScript code in `.js` file.